# DynamoDB health up actuator endpoint not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

I have this following piece of code :

```
    @Autowired
  public DynamoDBHealthIndicator(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDBClient, @Value("${session.tableName}") String tableName) {
    this.amazonDynamoDBClient = amazonDynamoDBClient;
    this.tableName = tableName;
  }

    @Override
      public Health health() {

    boolean dbOK = true;
    Map<String, String> healthDetails = new HashMap<>();
    if (amazonDynamoDBClient.listTables()
        .getTableNames()
        .contains(tableName)) {
      healthDetails.put(tableName, "FOUND");
    } else {
      healthDetails.put(tableName, "NOT FOUND");
      dbOK = false;
    }
    return dbOK ? Health.up()
        .withDetails(healthDetails)
        .build() : Health.down()
        .withDetails(healthDetails)
        .build();
     }
```

When I am visiting the endpoint for health - I am seeing DynamoDB down.

I see the value of the table getting populated correctly and queried the database and that worked fine too.
I tried some other ways but felt hacky. And the documentation says this is the one to get results correctly - what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: What documentation are you reading? Why not add some logging to see your results, for example log the results of list tables, and compare it to the condition to understand why it doesn't evaluate to true?

Comment: Update : Realized a problem yesterday evening. I stood up a container and added just one table to it - this time I got the result as success ! 
So, I started digging the lisTables number of results it is giving me back - turns out only 100 tables. Now with dynamoDB I am connecting on my dev env servers has 1000s of tables. That means I have to iterate - which would be wasteful. 
I am trying to use decribeTable and check if I get exception or not and decide the health that way.

Comment: or if anyone know any other method that can directly pinpoint the table and get result are welcome too.

Comment: DescribeTable is a control plane API and does not accurately represent the health of the table. You're better implementing canaries with dataplane ops.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue and the resolution  -
As pointed out above -
Realized a problem yesterday evening. I stood up a container and added just one table to it - this time I got the result as success ! So, I started digging the lisTables number of results it is giving me back - turns out only 100 tables. Now with dynamoDB I am connecting on my dev env servers has 1000s of tables. That means I have to iterate - which would be wasteful.

I used describeTable to resolve my issue - instead of iterating through the tables - I can try and just describe table and get the result status to see if my table is in ACTIVE status

something like :

```
dbOK = false;

try{
          describeTableResult = amazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(String.valueOf(tableName));
          if(describeTableResult != null){
            resultStatus = describeTableResult.getTable().getTableStatus();
            if(resultStatus.equals(DYNAMODB_DESIRED_TABLESTATUS)){
              log.info("dynamoDB table {} is healthy and in desired table status: {}", tableName, resultStatus);
              dbOK = true;
            }else{
              log.info("dynamoDB table {} is not healthy and is in status: {}", tableName, resultStatus);
            }
          }
        }catch(ResourceNotFoundException e){
          log.info("Table {} not found in dynamoDB", tableName);
        }
return dbOK;
```